# Set a table border with no conflicts with CSS borders

Tags: html, css, html-table

I just want to ask you if you  know the way to make table-border-setting free from 'Style'(CSS). As you see this 'Style' setting, its border is fixed to 1px. It looks nice but it won't let it change its border to the other pixel if I change border setting in 'table' tag.

I am thinking of applying CKEditor in my website and its table plugin will generate inline source code like `table border='number that users pick'`, but once style tag fix its border pixel, any table style set will not affect any style of table.

Source code below is exactly what I want it to look like unless it changes its border size when changing table style setting.

Would you  help me deal with this problem? It looked pretty easy at first, but it turned out it is something novice like me can't handle.

```
    <style type="text/css">
            p { border-color:  blue; border-style: solid; margin: 1px; }
            p.b2 { border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(199, 199, 199) ; }

            table, td {
                border:1px solid rgb(199, 199, 199);
                text-align: left;
            }


            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }


    </style>


    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:500px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>d</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>e</td>
                <td>f</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Add a tag with the language.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an easy solution. You can only apply CSS borders if `border` attribute is not present on the HTML.

So the solution is very simple. You can use  `:not()` CSS pseudo selector to select all tables that have not the `border` attribute, so you can push inside the parenthesis that attribute (closing into `[]` to tell CSS that's an attribute).

Let me show an example:

```css
table:not([border]) {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:500px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Without border attribute</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div style="height: 20px;"></div>
<table border="5" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:500px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">With border attribute</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So the entire solution is:

```
table:not([border]) {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Place your own style for tables with no border attribute.